# Applying Zorn's lemma in the proposition about cardinality of sets

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, order-theory

In *Real Analysis* book by Folland G., the following proposition is given:

> **0.7 Proposition.** *For any sets $X$ and $Y$, either $\mathrm{card}(X)\leq\mathrm{card}(Y)$ or $\mathrm{card}(Y)\leq\mathrm{card}(X)$.*
>
> *Proof.* Consider the set $\mathcal{J}$ of all injections from subsets of $X$ to $Y$. The members of $\mathcal{J}$ can be regarded as subsets of $X\times Y$, so $\mathcal{J}$ is partially ordered by inclusion. It is easily verified that Zorn's lemma applies, so $\mathcal{J}$ has a maximal element $f$, with (say) domain $A$ and range $B$. If $x_0\in X\setminus A$ and $y_0\in Y\setminus B$, then $f$ can be extended to an injection from $A\cup\{x_0\}$ to $Y\cup\{y_0\}$ by setting $f(x_0)=y_0$, contradicting maximality. Hence either $A=X$, in which case $\mathrm{card}(X)\leq\mathrm{card}(Y)$, or $B=Y$, in which case $f^{-1}$ is an injection from $Y$ to $X$ and $\mathrm{card}(Y)\leq\mathrm{card}(X)$. $\qquad\square$

I know that Zorn's lemma is as follows:

> **Zorn's lemma:** Suppose a partially ordered set P has the property that every chain in P has an upper bound in P. Then the set P contains at least one maximal element.

However, I am having difficulty in seeing how that quickly one can see that Zorn's lemma applies there as the textbook mentions. How can I show that any chain of $X\times Y$ has an upper bound? Could I say $X \times Y$ is itself the upper bound?

More explanation on the above proof would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the standard way to get upper bounds of a chain when the order is inclusion is to take the union of the chain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very common with Zorn's lemma arguments in which sets of some kind are ordered by inclusion for the upper bound of a chain to be its union. In this case, if $(f_i : A_i \to B_i)_{i \in I}$ is a chain of injections where each $A_i \subseteq X$ and each $B_i \subseteq Y$, then $\bigcup_{i \in I} f_i$ is an injection of $\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i \subseteq X$ into $\bigcup_{i \in I} B_i \subseteq Y$.