# Proof that if $card\,A \le card\,B$ and $card\,B \le card\,A$, then $card\,A = card\,B$

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation, set-theory

The question defines the '$\le$' operation on the cardinality of arbitrary sets A, and B as follows:
Let $\mathcal F$ be defined as the family of all injections from subsets of A onto B. Since $\mathcal F$ can be considered a family of subsets of the cartesian product of A and B, $A \times B$, it can be partially ordered by inclusion. Applying Zorn's Lemma, we conclude that $\mathcal F$ has a maximal element, $\mathcal f$. If the domain of $\mathcal f$ is A, then $card\,A \le card\,B$. The reason I believe it was defined this way was to show that '$\le$' is a linear ordering. I am not sure if that proof is necessary to solve this question. But that proof can be accessed here: [Applying Zorn's lemma in the proposition about cardinality of sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4025319/1265029).

It goes on to show that if $card\,A  \le card\,B$ and $card\,B \le card\,A$, then $card\,A = card\,B$. The question asks to complete the proof. This is how it goes:
Let $f: A \to B$ and $g: B \to A$ be injections.
If $a \in A \cap rng\,g$, we have $g^{-1}(a) \in B$.
If $g^{-1}(a) \in rng\,f$, we have $f^{-1}(g^{-1}(a)) \in A$.
The process is to continue indefinitely or till it terminates with an element in $A$ \ rng $g$ or $B$ \ rng $f$. The three cases become disjoint sets $A_{\infty}, \, A_A, \, A_B$ whose union is A. Similarly, B can be decomposed into $B_{\infty}, \, B_B, \, B_A$.
It states that f maps $A_{\infty}$ onto $B_{\infty}$ and $A_A\,onto\,B_A$ and g maps $B_B\,onto\,A_B$.

1. How exactly does this mapping work? It intuitively makes sense but I have not been able to put something concrete down.

If we define $h: A \to B$ by $h(a) = f(a)$ if $a \in A_{\infty} \cup A_A$ and $h(a) = g^{-1}(a)$ if $a \in A_B$, we find that h is injective. The question ends there.

2. I have an idea of how to show that h is surjective. If $b \in B_{\infty}$ then $b \in B \cap rng\,f$ and $f^{-1}(b) \in A$. Since the process has to continue indefinitely, $f^{-1}(b) \in rng\,g$.  Thus,  $f^{-1}(b) \in A \cap rng\,g$, meaning that $g^{-1}(f^{-1}(b)) \in B$ and so on. Thus, $f^{-1}(b)$ is in $A_{\infty}$. A similar argument can be used to show that if $b \in B_B$, then there exists $f^{-1}(b) \in A_B$ and if $b \in B_A$ then there exists $f^{-1}(b) \in A_A$. All of these pre-images would satisfy the condition of h (due to its injectivity I presume) and thus, h is surjective. I ask for help in making this proof more rigorous.
3. Even if h has been proven to both be surjective and injective, how does that show the equality of the cardinalities of the sets? I checked the question and equality was not defined for cardinality. Is there some trivial notion of equality I could apply here that I could link to my proof of subjectivity and injectivity and that would not be circular in nature? Is this the right way to go? If it was, why couldn't I use the fact that we had two injective functions from one set to the other to prove the equality instead?
4. If it is necessary to do so, how can I link this proof with the ordering, '$\le$'? I have not mentioned it once in the proof and that worries me.

Comment: Re 4: you don't yet know that $\leq$ is "an ordering". Right now it's just shorthand for "there is an injection from the set on the left to the set on the right." It is easy to show this relation is reflexive and transitive, but you do not know it is an order *until* you prove it is anti-symmetric... which is what you are trying to prove. So it is a *good* thing tou haven't mentioned this "order", as that would likely make your argument circular.

Comment: Oh. That makes sense. I am grateful. That means I am also wrong in stating that the page I linked proves that '$\le$' is a linear ordering. It would prove instead that  '$\le$' for cardinality is simply a relation that applies to any two sets. I do have another question though. Should I not use the very definition of the relation, '$\le$' in the proof?

Comment: The linked-to page shows that (assuming the Axiom of Choice; in fact the statement is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice) given any two sets, either there is an injection from $A$ to $B$ or there is an injection from $B$ to $A$. In the absence of a proof that the relation $\leq$ is anti-symmetric, that only proves that it is a *total* relation (a binary relation on $X$ is total if for all $x,y\in X$, either $x$ is related to $y$ or $y$ is related to $x$). And you *are* using the definition: because you are using the *injections* $f$ and $g$, which come from $A\leq B$ and $B\leq A$, respectively

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of the proof of the Cantor-Bernstein Theorem (the statement that if there is an injection $f\colon A\to B$ and an injection $g\colon B\to A$, then there is a bijection $h\colon A\to B$) is to prove that the relation $\leq$ among cardinalities is a partial order. You don't know that ahead of time.

Say two sets $A$ and $B$ are *equipollent*, denoted $A\approx B$, if and only if there is a bijection between $A$ and $B$. It is easy to verify this is an equivalence relation. Now define the relation $\preceq$ on sets by saying that $A\preceq B$ if and only if there is an injective function $f\colon A\to B$. It is easy to show that:

1. $A\preceq A$ for all $A$; that is, $\preceq$ is reflexive.
2. If $A\preceq B$ and $B\preceq C$, then $A\preceq C$; that is, $\preceq$ is transitive.
3. If $A\approx X$ and $B\approx Y$, then $A\preceq B$ if and only if $X\preceq Y$.

The point of the statement you are trying to prove is to show that

> If $A\preceq B$ and $B\preceq A$, then $A\approx B$.

This will prove that $\preceq$ is a (partial) order among the equipollency equivalence classes of sets.

The page you linked to is irrelevant to these facts. Instead, it proves that, assuming the Axiom of Choice, the relation $\preceq$ is a *total* relation among sets. Together with the fact that $\preceq$ is a partial order on equipollency equivalence classes, it will show that $\preceq$ is a *total* order on those equivalence classes. (In fact, this statement, known as Bernstein's Theorem, is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice.)

You want to prove that if $A\preceq B$ and $B\preceq A$, then $A\approx B$. Because we are assuming $A\preceq B$, there is an injective function $f\colon A\to B$. Because we are assuming $B\preceq A$, then there is an injective function $g\colon B\to A$. The existence of these functions comes directly from the definition of $\preceq$.

You have partitioned $A$ into three sets: $A_{\infty}$, $A_A$, and $A_B$. You have likewise partitioned $B$ into $B_{\infty}$, $B_A$, and $B_B$.

Note that because of how they are defined, if $a\in A_{\infty}$,  then $f(a)\in B_{\infty}$. If $a\in A_A$, then $f(a)\in B_A$; and if $a\in B_B$, theN $f(b)\in B_B$. Similarly, if $b\in B_{\infty}$ then $g(b)\in A_{\infty}$; if $b\in B_A$, then $g(b)\in A_A$; and if $b\in B_{B}$, then $g(b)\in A_B$.

Moreover, because every element in $B_A$ lies in $\mathrm{range}(f)$, it follows that $f(A_A)=B_A$: we saw above that $f(A_A)\subseteq B_A$; and that if $f(a)\in B_A$ then $a\in A_A$, so $B_A=B_A\cap\mathrm{range}(f)=f(A_A)$. A symmetric argument shows that $g(B_B)=A_B$. Likewise, if $b\in B_{\infty}$, then $b$ lies in $\mathrm{range}(f)$ and must be the image of an element of $A_{\infty}$, so $f(A_{\infty})=B_{\infty}$. That addresses your point 1.

For point 2, that $h$ is surjective follows from the fact that $B_A$, $B_B$, and $B_{\infty}$ form a partition of $B$. Given any $y\in B$, if $y\in B_A$, then $y\in f(A_A)$, so there exists $a\in A_A$ with $f(a)=y$. Then $h(a)=y$ by definition of $h$. If $y\in B_{\infty}$, then there exists $a\in A_{\infty}$ such that $f(a)=y$, and then $h(a)=y$ by the definition of $h$. Finally, if $y\in B_B$, then $g(y)\in A_B$, and $h(g(y)) = y$ by the way that $h$ is defined. Thus, $h$ is surjective.

For point 3: since $h$ is both injective and surjective, then it is bijective. Therefore, $A\approx B$, since "$\approx$" means "there is a bijection between them.

Now, we **define** "two sets have the same cardinality" to mean, *precisely*, "there is a bijection between them". That is, $\mathrm{card}(A)=\mathrm{card}(B)$ is shorthand for $A\approx B$ ($A$ is equipollent to $B$), which is shorthand for "there is a bijection between $A$ and $B$). So once you prove that there is a bijection between two sets, you are proving that they have the same cardinality, because that is what "have the same cardinality" means: that there is a bijection between the two sets. That's point 3.

For point 4, you don't know that $\leq$ is an ordering (among equipollence equivalence classes). So you shouldn't use it until you prove Cantor-Bernstein; so of course you are not using that it is an ordering: you are trying to *prove* that it is one.

Comment: I am satisfied. Thank you.